# Length parbox LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am trying to build a table on LaTeX with parbox. I have found how to do with parbox. However, the length between rows makes the text so pack. Do you know how to increase the length?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

{\raggedright
\vspace{3pt} \noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{108pt}|p{223pt}|p{52pt}|}
\hline
\parbox{108pt}{\raggedright 
Attribute
} & \parbox{223pt}{\raggedright 
Description
} & \parbox{52pt}{\raggedright 
Characteristic
} \\
\hline
\parbox{108pt}{\raggedright 
Language
} & \parbox{223pt}{\raggedright
Programming language of the source code.
} & \parbox{52pt}{\raggedright \multirow{5}{*}{
Project
}} \\
\cline{1-3}
\parbox{108pt}{\raggedright 
Team\_size
} & \parbox[70em]{223pt}{\raggedright
Number of active core team members during the last 3 months prior to creation.
} &  \\
\cline{1-3} 
\parbox[15em]{108pt}{\raggedright 
Perc\_external\_contribs
} & \parbox{223pt}{\raggedright 
Ratio of commits from external contributors over core team members in the last 3 months prior to creation of pull request.
} &  \\
\cline{1-2} 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2pt}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think this question belongs to https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have tried with \parbox[15em]{108pt}{\raggedright  according to:

\parbox[position][height][inner-pos]{width}{text}

included on http://herbert.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/html/latex2e/$5cparbox.html

However, I don't get the space between the rows :(

Answer (score 0):

The `tabular` columns are already set using a `p`aragraph specification, so there's no need to set each cell using a `\parbox` (of similar width) as well.

You might be interested in [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) as it allows for a flexibly-width `X`-column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% Loads the array package

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}p{108pt}|>{\raggedright}X|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{62pt}|}
  \hline
  Attribute & Description & Characteristic \\
  \hline
  Language & Programming language of the source code. & Project \\
  \hline
  Team\_size & Number of active core team members during the last 3 months prior to creation. & \\
  \hline
  Perc\_external\_contribs & Ratio of commits from external contributors over core team 
  members in the last 3 months prior to creation of pull request. & \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to adjust the padding further, consider reading up on [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764).